# How to identify malicious .deb files / sources?

Tags: software-center

When I download and a .deb file from the web and open it in the Ubuntu Software Center it says "Only install this file if you trust the origin." But it's not at all clear to me how I am supposed to evaluate an origin such as www.whatever.com is trustworthy or not.

I understand the degree of risk inherent in installing software which is not in a trusted repository and/or not open source. I'm interested in managing that risk because I have found a number applications fall into this category (e.g. Skype).

So is there not a website or something that tracks packages which are known to be malicious or suspicious?

Answer (score 1):

After asking this, I noticed that even for these kinds of packages, user reviews show up in Software Center. At least if there were ransomeware or something very obviously malicious in a package, users could report it as a negative review.